# How can I show the native numeric keypad in the focus of a textarea in the ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

I need a textarea to call the native numeric keypad because the textarea only accepts numbers and I want to make the client more comfortable when typing. I am making an application with Ionic 3, is it possible to do this?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/ are you looking for the above link

Comment: @MohanGopi I believe the question was just for the numeric keyboard (phone dialing for instance) and not the full keyboard. I do not see an option on your referenced plugin to show this smaller keyboard.

Comment: Exacly i want to show only the numeric keyboard.

Comment: did you solve this ? @ElderCarvalho

Comment: @George unfortunately it is not possible to do this with textarea, I had to use adjacent tel-type inputs.